# Pitch shifter questions?

Tags: fpga, adc

Hi I was wondering how to implement a pitch shifter?

So I have an audio input signal sampled at 48KHz and a 256 sample FFT. So my binsize is 48000/256=187.5 Hz per bin.

From the 256 samples I am taking the bin that has the maximum magnitude, and then in order to find the frequency I am folowing this formula:

frequency= binIndex * binSize.

Then I am taking multiply this frequency by 2 in order to make a pitch shift.

Comment: How is finding the frequency related to pitch shifting?

Comment: There are at least two different ways to do pitch shifting: harmonically where each frequency gets moved up by some multiplicative factor, or linearly, which would sound like a single sideband radio tuned off frequency. Multiplying the values in the bins by a constant won't do anything except amplify the sound.

Comment: Theran- frequency= binIndex*binSize. I can find the binIndex through a search algorithim by finding which bin of the 256 samples have the maximum magnitude. we already know the binSize by the sampleRate/sampleSize.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution will shift the pitch up a fixed amount based on the frequency of the loudest "sine wave".  For example, if you feed it a 440 Hz sine wave then it will output a 880 Hz sine wave.  880 Hz is one octave higher than 440, so you're good so far.

However, music is not just a single sine wave.  A single note will have harmonics.  Normally each harmonic is an integer multiple (or divisor) of the fundamental.  Let's say that your 440 Hz note has a harmonic at 880 Hz.  That harmonic is at a lower volume than the fundamental.

When you run this through your algorithm, it will pick out the 440 Hz and shift everything up another 440 Hz.  What ends up is that the fundamental correctly comes out as 880 Hz, but the harmonic comes out as 1320 Hz but it should be 1760 Hz.

The result is that your single note is now out of tune with itself!  Now consider that a single note is not just one fundamental and one harmonic, but there could be hundreds of harmonics-- each out of tune with the other.  Ouch!

To further make things difficult, you cannot differentiate between notes accurately enough.  For example, middle C is 523.25 Hz.  But C# above middle C is 554.37 Hz.  Both of these will fall into the same FFT bin, so you will shift them the same # of Hz even though they are different notes that require a different shift amount.  More out of tune shifting.

FFT's and Inverse FFT's are not used for professional pitch shifters.  Well, sometimes FFTs are used but the bin data is not just moved and put into an inverse FFT to get the pitch shifted audio-- doing so results in bad sounding noises.

Professional pitch shifting algorithms are all patented, which has some good and bad things.  For you the good thing is that a patent search will uncover all sorts of documentation on how professionals do it.

Comment: So how would I go about this then to find the frequency? Would I just find the frequency of by the bin index, and multiply that by then bin size for each and every sample out of the 256 samples? So if frequency=binIndex*binSize, would I just use this formula for each bin and that'll give me a pitch shift?

Comment: @bobert Pitch shifting is one of the hardest DSP algorithms to do.  Years ago I tried to do it using FFTs and Inverse FFTs.  A DSP expert that I worked with basically laughed at me and told me that it wouldn't work.  I stubbornly worked on the FFT approach for another 2 weeks before giving up in defeat, admitting that FFTs are not the way to do it.  10 years later I still have not made a working pitch shifting algorithm.  Now here I am telling you to give up on the FFTs, and to go read the patents to see how it's really done.

Comment: On the plus side, it is really fun to take a song and strip out the lead vocals.  Then badly pitch shift the lead vocals and mix it back into the lead vocal-less version.  The end result is a song where the lead vocals are way out of tune.

Comment: Can you lead me to where I can find these patents?

Comment: @bobert  Go to Google Patents (https://www.google.com/?tbm=pts), and type in "pitch shift".  I came up with over 5,000 hits.

Comment: Yes, you obviously cannot just add a delta to the frequency. Pitch shifting does not translate frequency, but rather scales it. We call it "shifting" because we perceive pitch logarithmically. Everything moves by the same number of semitones.

Answer (score 0):

A natural approach for pitch shifting is to sample incoming audio at one speed and play it back at another.  The natural problem with this is that the outgoing audio would either increasingly lag behind the incoming audio or get ahead of it.  To overcome that, if the incoming audio will have a single dominant pitch (e.g. it represents a single person's voice, or a single instrument string, etc.) one can sample the data at a high speed (possibly using a digital filter to produce a waveform with more samples per second than the original), search the high-speed waveform for places that seem to more-or-less match, and then either duplicate or omit the content between such places as needed to keep the output waveform in time with the input.  Depending upon the source content, this approach may work well or it may sound very "garbly".  There are various ways by which one can try to "smooth out" the resulting splices; such approaches will cause things to sound less garbly, but more "muddy".  I have an inexpensive guitar effects box that uses this approach for harmonizer function; it sounds fine if I play one note at a time with no overlap, but if I fail to completely mute one string before plucking another the resulting sound will be garbled.

Answer (score 0):

Pitch shifting benefits from treatment of the phase.  The width of the bins is too crude to represent pitch accurately. However, if the assumption can be made that none of the bins contains more than one sinusoid of the original signal (the resolution of your FFT is fine enough that each interesting component of the signal gets its own "private" bin) then the phase information from the FFT contains precise information about the location of the pitch within each bin.  This is because when the signal is convoluted with the sinusoid basis, it will exhibit a rotating phase.  For instance, if the center frequency of a bin is 400Hz, and a 390 Hz signal lands into that bin, the phase will rotate 10 Hz. Of course, you don't see the rotation in a single FFT window, where you have just a single phase value for that bin (encoded as the argument of the complex number). But if it is tracked over successive windows, the phase variation between successive windows of the signal will appear as a 10 Hz rotation, telling you exactly that the tone is 10 Hz off-center from that bin's center frequency.

In a pitch shifting operation, you can manipulate the phase so that the offset between the bin frequency is properly translated.  So for instance if the 390 Hz tone is supposed to be doubled to 780 Hz, then relative to a bin that is centered on 800 Hz, the phase rotation has to be 20 Hz now. In other words, the "heterodyning beats" between the bin frequencies and actual frequencies have to be subject to the frequency scaling in order to do an accurate job.

Take a look at the [phase vocoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_vocoder) Wikipedia article, which is largerly content-free, but has a few valuable external links.

Answer (score 0):

i've been attempting a de facto fft implementation for a while, no luck and not much help.

i scaled (a "pitch shifter" is a frequency scaler.. frequency shifting is, as mentioned, discretely different) the cartesian coordinates using the sinc function, which has exactly the same effect as changing the read speed of a sample in the time domain, except it repeats the function for upwards shifts, so you might as well use a PSOLA kinda thing. dspdimension describes a method for shifting without changing the time domain, but it's probably fairly crap as there is no bin interpolation.

i have attempted to then convert to polar form and process the phase after shifting in cartesian form (the bins accumulate the interpolated data) and then converting to polar, and have not found a method of processing phase in a single shot analysis that works. the dspdimension method uses the difference between analysed frames..